# How to disable interaction on NSTextAttachment?

Tags: ios, uitextview, nstextattachment

In a UITextView with editable = YES and selectable = NO, I want to disable interaction on NSTextAttachments. To be more specific, I don't want long presses on NSTextAttachments to highlight the attachment images. I want these long press gestures to be passed to UITextView as normal text selection gestures.

What I have tried:
`textView:shouldInteractWithTextAttachment:inRange:` can prevent the action sheet but can not prevent the temporary highlight of the attachment image nor can it make these long presses be handled as text selection gestures.

Answer (score 2):

`UITextView` has several installed gesture recognisers. There is one that is a subclass of `UITapGestureRecognizer` which you can disable.